# How do I check to see if #sel has an option based on the text value? ("Option1") . i want exact comparision

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code

```js
var opt = 'Option1';
if ($('#sel option:contains('+ opt +')').length) {
   alert('This option exists')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
<option value="0">Option1</option>
<option value="1">Option2</option>
<option value="2">Option3</option>
<option value="3">Option4</option>
</select>
```

if another option contains Option112,The above code selecting two options "Option1" and "Option112". but i want to select only Option1.

My select box contains thousands of values,so i am woorying about iteration.Is it possible with predefined methods.If yes How can I?`enter code here`

Comment: Instead of your if-block your might use [`console.log($('#sel option').filter((i, el) => el.innerText === opt).length)`](https://jsfiddle.net/FPDCu/133/) This selects all options and filters to only include the ones which contain the exact text.

Comment: It is working fine,but also i want case insensitive,The above code is case sensitive nature

Comment: I'm sure you can combine some `toLowerCase()` methods to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Yes,It's working now thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()` to get the text and then compare the text.

```
 var opt = 'option1'; 

 if ($('#sel option:selected').html().toLowerCase() === opt){
     alert('This option exists');
 }
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FPDCu/134/)